# No such file to load -- 'gem name' using require

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using gem `differ` https://github.com/pvande/differ

I have a helper

```
require 'differ'
module AnswersHelper
    def self.getDiff (text1, text2)
        Differ.format = :html
        diff = Differ.diff_by_word(@current, @original)
    end
end
```

But I get an error No such file to load -- differ

If I remove require line
I get an error at that line

```
Differ.format = :html
```

> uninitialized constant QuestionsController::Differ

When I tried following commands in rails console it worked

```
require 'differ'

diff = Differ.diff_by_word("text1","text2)
```

I  have  gem `differ` in my gemfile
and also I tried

```
require_relative 'differ'
```

and

```
require './differ'
```

UPD: seems restarting server helps, I'll check it right now

Comment: did you run `bundle install`? Run `bundle show differ` within your project directory and post the output here.

Comment: @Aleksey yes of course

Answer (score 0):

Restarting server helped........

Comment: the first thing you should do every time you install new gem